# The SVG text node disappear after change its text content

Tags: javascript, ios, svg

```
svg:
 <text xml:space="preserve" y="228" x="349.98" text-anchor="middle" stroke-width="0" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" style="cursor: move; pointer-events: inherit;" font-size="24" font-family="serif" id="cur_b">cur_b</text>  <text xml:space="preserve" y="222" x="103.98" text-anchor="middle" stroke-width="0" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" style="cursor: move; pointer-events: inherit;" font-size="24" font-family="serif" id="cur_a">cur_a</text>  <text xml:space="preserve" y="229" x="590.0211" text-anchor="middle" stroke-width="0" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" style="cursor: move; pointer-events: inherit;" font-size="24" font-family="serif" id="cur_c">cur_c</text>

NSString* theJS = @ "var theNode0 = document.getElementById('cur_a');
theNode0.textContent='200A';
theNode0.setAttribute('fill','#FF0000');
var theNode1 = document.getElementById('cur_c');
theNode1.textContent='200A';
theNode1.setAttribute('fill','#00FF00');"

 [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:theJS];
```

The SVG text node value is changed but disappeared after about one second.